# ¿Como sumar los valores de las mismas posiciones de arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero sumar los valores de las mismas posiciones? He aquí mi arreglo:

```
var arr1 = ["1","2","3","4"];
var arr2 = ["2","1","3","4"];
```

El resultado tiene que ser:

```
var NuevoArreglo = ["3","3","6","8"];
```

Espero la ayuda.

Comment: disculpa, pero por que las ultimas posiciones del nuevo arreglo no son 6 y 8?

Comment: Buena Observación, jejeje como lo hice manual, no me percate y solo sume los dos primeros, ahora lo corrigo, Gracias ^^!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [2,1,3,4];
var r = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
  r[i] =arr1[i]+arr2[i];
}

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Simple y sencillo, muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 3):

Como alternativa, voy a mostrarte como hacerlo usando la función [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).

Debes saber que el método `map` sirve para procesar un arreglo y obtener otro arreglo pero transformado por medio de una función (que hace la transformación);  Quizás te interese saber que es uno de los métodos esenciales para trabajar con arreglos, junto a [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) el cual se usa para consolidar/resumir arreglos de datos.

La intención detrás de `map` es transformar cada elemento en un nuevo elemento, con esto en mente... considera el siguiente ejemplo.

```js
// si en lugar de cadenas (ej. "1") usas numeros (ej [1,2,3,4])
// puedes eliminar las partes de Number abajo y el map de toString.
var arr1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var arr2 = ["2", "1", "3", "4"];

// ahora usamos el map
var result = arr1.map(Number)
  .map( (item, ix) => item + Number(arr2[ix]) )
  .map( (item) => item.toString() );

// salida
console.log(result);
```

Explicación

- El primer `.map(Number)` convierte `"1"` en `1` (tipo de dato numérico)
- El segundo `.map( (item, ix) => item + Number(arr2[ix]) )` por cada numero, busca y convierte el numero correspondiente de `arr2` y los suma.
- El ultimo `.map( (item) => item.toString() )`, vuelve convertir cada numero en un string para obtener el resultado.

Nota: he usado varios maps para ejemplificar mejor como se utilizan, no es necesario hacerlo en tantos pasos, puede hacerse en una sola ejecución:

```
arr1.map( (item, ix) => (Number(item) + Number(arr2[ix])).toString() );
```

Ahora..

Si en lugar de cadenas, te quedan bien los números, la cosa es mucho mas simple.

```js
// si en lugar de cadenas (ej. "1") usas numeros (ej [1,2,3,4])
// puedes eliminar las partes de Number abajo y el map de toString.
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 1, 3, 4];

var result = arr1.map( (item, ix) => item + arr2[ix] );
// salida
console.log(result);
```

Espero que te sirva.

Nota: Me parece mas legible usar `map` que usar un un loop tipo `for each` o estructuras de control similar pues se ve como una cadena de funciones y no hay tantos corchetes. Pero es cosa de gustos.

Comment: Buena respuesta, es parecida a la mía, y responden realmente a la pregunta con los datos mistrados por el usuario. Lo único que veo un poco redundante es el uso de dos maps, cuando con uno puedes hacer todas las operaciones. Aún así buenas explicación. =)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo si, contestamos casi al mismo tiempo ;) solo quize hacer incapie en como funciona map en si, en lugar de solamente darle una solición. Para mi tiene mas sentido que convierta esos arrays a numeros.

Comment: Sí, como he dicho buena explicación del uso de map. Pero en cuestión de optimización puedes hacer la operación de suma y conversión de una vez, en lugar de recorrer 3 veces la lista. Aún así, +1, ya que creo que es mejor respuesta que las que tienen más puntuación.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta de esta manera:

```
var arr1 = ["1","2","3","4"];
var arr2 = ["2","1","3","4"];
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (arr1[i] != arr2[i] ) {
    result[i] = parseint(arr1[i])+parseint(arr2[i]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí te dejo un `script` donde haces la suma mediante un forEach, esta forma de hacerlo es contemplando el nuevo EcmaScript 6.

Observa el uso del `arr1.forEach`.

```js
var arr1 = ["1","2","3","4"];
var arr2 = ["2","1","3","4"];
var total = new Array(); //Creamos un array Vacio
arr1.forEach((a,b) => { total.push(Number(a)+Number(arr2[b])) } ); //Iteramos el array llamado: arr1. Con el método Number los declaramos enteros y los sumamos
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás la opción más sencilla sea usar `Array.map()`:

```js
var arr1 = ["1","2","3","4"];
var arr2 = ["2","1","3","4"];

var nuevo = arr1.map((x,i)=> (+x + +arr2[i]) + "");
console.log(nuevo);
```

Según tu pregunta, los Arrays iniciales contienen `String`s y quieres sumarlos y volverlos a convertir en `String`, según la salida esperada que muestras en la pregunta.

```
(+x + +arr2[i]) + ""
```

Prefijando a cada variable con el símbolo `+` estamos diciendo que convierta a número la variable. Y añadiendo `+ ""` convertimos el número final sumado en String.

Ten en cuenta que ambas listas deben tener el mismo tamaño.